# iOS data usage specifics - iTunes Accounts

Tags: ios, cellular-data, iphone

I'm trying to find out what does "iTunes Accounts" traffic stands for on iOS, since it has gobbled 850MB on cellular data in 13 days.
I have iTunes Match on but have disabled the Music app to access data on cellular networks.
I'm on iOS 8.3 since today, data was consumed on 8.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably iTunes & App Store background downloads.

You can prevent these, so it only updates when you're connected to wifi, in
Settings > iTunes & App Store…  by disabling Cellular Data
[I also prevent all automatic downloads, so mine only updates from iTunes itself, on my Mac]

[image]

Comment: Thanks!
I'll check that and report on usage on a few days.

Comment: I had "Use Cellular Data" on, all the rest deactivated.

Comment: Cellular data off and the drainage stopped. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it might be iCloud documents syncing Settings -> iCloud -> iCloud Drive (scroll to the bottom to turn off cellular data).

Also seems like iTunes music "new music mix" might come in under this.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, my phone (iOS 10 now) shows this as 129MB in the last month since reset, with **all the above turned off**

I don't even play Music on my phone, only listen to Podcasts (which has a separate total of 74MB).

Seriously confused!

Sorry I don't have an answer but thought this might be a useful data point confirming that a significant amount can be run up **without** the data being enabled tor *iTunes & App Store*