# System Data Usage - iOS v10.0.2 AT&T

Tags: itunes, accounts, services, data

iTunes Accounts in System Services is draining over 3.5 GB of data per cycle (Settings-->Cellular-->System Services-->iTunes Accounts). I monitored it closely during this data cycle.

I have disabled Settings-->iTunes and App Stores-->Use Cellular Data. I have also disabled Settings-->Cellular-->Wi-Fi Assist. Does anyone know how I can determine what is causing this?

I have a large data plan and I'm upset, I can't imagine how people with smaller data plans survive at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS data usage specifics - iTunes Accounts](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/180859/ios-data-usage-specifics-itunes-accounts)

Comment: Thank you For your reply Jaime.I have 'Use Cellular Data' turned off and the answer does not address my issue. What is posting protocol? Do I leave my thread or piggy back the one you linked? Thanks!

Comment: If your question differs from the one I marked as possible duplicate, explain the difference by editing your question so it doesn't get closed.

Comment: Thanks Jaime, I edited my post to reflect I have disabled Use Cellular Data. The question is still similar but the answer must be different (I am not sure if I could have reopened your linked thread, I looked and didn't see a way to do so; all I could find is Add Answer option).

Comment: Stack Exchange works differently from most forums: you ask a question, and people answer that specific question. Subsequent questions must be asked separately. If you ask a question that has been asked before, it may get marked as duplicate.

Comment: I don't see an option to disable Cellular Data for System services, could you explain _in your question_ where did you disable it?

Comment: I see, you disabled it on the iTunes & App Store settings, right? Please explain that in your question if that is the case.

Comment: Thanks Jaime, I think it's good now. Hopefully someone knows what is causing this.